# Android Emulator No Internet Problem On Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I try to connect wifi from Android Emulator but it gives no internet problem.

To run it, my command is:

```
emulator @<your_emulator_name> -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried without `-dns-server` ?

Comment: @Philippe sure :D